# Call DB2 stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, db2

After reading an interesting article online : [Calling DB2 stored procedures from .NET applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=net-calling-stored-procedures-from-applications)

I'd like to share an issue recently encountered with a derived code :

```
DateTime transa_date = DateTime.ParseExact(trandate, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection(MyDb2ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

try
{
    // MyDb2Connection.Open();
    // conn.Open();

    // assume a DB2Connection conn
    DB2Transaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    procName = "MYTBLSCHEMA.TEST";
    procCall = "CALL MYTBLSCHEMA.TEST(@NAME, @ADDRESS_LINE, @REGNUM, @TRANSA)";

    cmd.Transaction = trans;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = procCall; 

    // Register input-output and output parameters for the DB2Command
    cmd.Parameters.Add( new DB2Parameter("@NAME", name));       #of string type
    cmd.Parameters.Add( new DB2Parameter("@ADDRESS_LINE", adr)); #of string type
    cmd.Parameters.Add( new DB2Parameter("@REGNUM", reg));  #of string type
    cmd.Parameters.Add( new DB2Parameter("@TRANSA", transa_date)); #of date type (in DB2 table)

    // Call the stored procedure
    Console.WriteLine(" Call stored procedure named " + procName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The above code neither generates an exception at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` nor inserts the (expected) row into the table.

Hence, a Hope to understand through this post the rationale underlying such phenomenon.

Thanks.

**N.B**: Executing (manually)

```
CALL MYTBLSCHEMA.TEST('test', 'test_address_', 'test_num', 2021-01-01)
```

from the IDE does work (e.g. insert the row into the table).

DB2 version: 11.5.6.0.00000.008

Comment: `DB2Parameter("@ADDRESS_LINE", adr)` - the parameter is however named `@ADDRESS`

Comment: ```@NAME```, ```@ADDRESS_LINE```, ```@REGNUM```,```@TRANSA``` refer to the Table columns (namely respectively ```NAME```, ```ADDRESS_LINE```, ```REGNUM```, ```TRANSA```) and ```adr``` is the variable extracted from the form and associated to the ```ADDRESS_LINE``` column. Hope it helps;

Comment: No, `@ADDRESS_LINE` would refer to a parameter you use in your SQL statement, but there is no such parameter, only one called `@ADDRESS`.

Comment: I've edited the post after correcting the typo. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unless something is missing from the documentation highlighted in the post. Otherwise i do not see any anomaly in the code. what do you think?

Comment: Where do you commit the transaction you started ?

Comment: @CaiusJard: nowhere as reflected into the documentation.

Comment: You started a transaction that you didn't commit? That's the first place I'd start looking if I was wondering why I couldn't find data that I just inserted..

Comment: @CaiusJard: Sure. Actually I assumed that if a ```complete``` example (omitting the ```commit``` part) was released online for documentation purposes, à priori it meant it should work without further adjustments.

Comment: @CaiusJard: I've eventually removed the ```transaction``` part to avoid the ```commit```, and everything now works, as expected. Thanks for your guidance with regards to ```transaction / commit``` .

Answer (score 1):

I'd either remove this line:

```
DB2Transaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
```

Or I'd add this line at the end of the `try`:

```
trans.Commit();
```

As to which you'd choose; as it's a single stored procedure, unless there's some internal overriding concern within the sproc that makes sense to have a transaction to be started outside it cover it, I'd remove it. If you have, or plan to have multiple operations that must either all-succeed or all-fail, then I'd keep it/commit it..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Caius. As indicated in my previous command (22h ago), the removal of the ```transaction``` part (e.g.```DB2Transaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction()```) has solved the issue. However, I've just tried your suggestion with regards to ```trans.Commit()```: To avoid an ```exception``` I recommend to insert this command just before ```cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()``` and not at the end of the ```try```. Best

Comment: *insert this command just before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`* - But that's not how transactions work; you don't commit them before you do work (ExecuteNonQuery performs work on the database); you commit them *after* you do work. See the example from IBM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=begintransaction- - the transaction is started, multiple commands are executed and then the transaction is committed. If you commit a transaction before you do anything, it's a non-op.

Comment: If your stored procedure is not compatible with a transaction for some reason, then you should not start one (or you should not run a transaction at all) before you execute the sproc